# fetch download file from server nginx+php-fpm

Tags: javascript, php, asynchronous, request, fetch

Friends, tell me.
There is nginx, it has a mp4 streaming module on it.
The condition is also set:

```
if ($request_filename ~* ^.*?/([^/]*?)$)
{
set $filename $1;
add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=$filename";
}
```

to send the mp4 file to the user if he requests it directly. those. it plays in the video player, and if it wants to download it is downloaded.

The task is as follows:
you need to somehow organize the mp4 download through fetch (mode: "no-cors") so that it loads and / or into the browser’s cache and the download dialog is shown to the user.

I use PHP to handle fetch requests. But the video file goes directly. I tried using php headers to give the file to be downloaded to fetch, but it doesn’t work out ..

It turns out, I request the mp4 file like this:

```
fetch ("'. $fileToDownload.'", {/*$fileToDownload - PHP variable — URL to video file*/
method: "get",
headers: {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "site.org",
},
mode: "no-cors"
});
```

it is loaded into the browser cache and, of course, after the download is completed, nothing happens. it just lies there, and the file save window does not appear, and I don’t know how to do it ...
in addition, if you immediately give this file for download, by clicking on the same link as the fetch request was, the file is NOT taken from the cache that fetch did, but it downloads again.

Other methods, such as pseudo-click on a link, do not work, because there is a delay timer .... Like loading starts in 10 seconds. And because of the timer, the simulation of clicking on the link does not work, because if you put it for more than 3 seconds, the window is blocked by the browser policy.

I tried to use download.js, but it goes through xhr, and through it does not give the mode property, and the download is blocked, because the domain from where the file is downloaded is different.

I suspect you need to use serviceworker to intercept the cache? ..

Spent the whole day, but it turns out my way out is to only call the user, after the timer expires, click on the download button, which seems to be hidden until the end of the timer.

I just need to give the user a file to download.
But due to the fact that it lies on another domain, and is also given as an application / octet stream, the download is blocked by the browser.

window. open as well as window. location = .. cannot be used due to the timer, windows and redirects are blocked by the browser, i.e. mime type does not match received content (video / mp4)

Answer (score 0):

I partially found the answer in Google...

> Warning: For cross-origin resources, make sure your CORS headers are
>   set properly. As we can't create an array buffer from an opaque
>   response retrieved with fetch (videoFileUrl, {mode: 'no-cors'}), we
>   won't be able to feed any video or audio element.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/fast-playback-with-video-preload